# What does Kabincho mean?

Tags: genshiken

In Genshiken Nidaime, episode 6, Kuchiki Manabu got some flak for being useless, and Kabincho! was his reaction (10:41). Is  this just more of his nonsensical outbursts or is this a reference to something?

[image: kabincho!]

Comment: I have no source or anything else to substatiate this, but I assumed it was just nonsense similar to what Nodame would say (from Nodame Cantabile) as an exclamation.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in English or Japanese about this. The hits I get for the term in Japanese are all dead ends, and there's nothing of mention in English. I strongly suspect it's just a nonsensical word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no source or anything else to substatiate this, but I assumed it was just nonsense similar to what Nodame would say (from Nodame Cantabile) as an exclamation. It may be that later on we find out what Kuchiki is shouting about, but as of now, there's no indication that "Kabincho" actually means anything.

Also see Logan's comment about his research into the word in English or Japanese.